# A shortcut for analytic continuation?

Tags: analytic-number-theory, zeta-functions, analytic-continuation, summation-method

Let $P(x)$ be a nonconstant integer polynomial with nonnegative coëfficiënts such that the equation $y= P(y)$ has only one real solution $q$.

Let $x_1=P(0)$ and $x_n = P(x_{n-1})$.

$$f(z) = \sum_{n>1} \frac{1}{x_n ^ z}$$

Consider the analytic continuation of $f(z) : F(z)$.

If $q$ is in the range of $F(r)$ for $dom(r)$ being the reals, and there are no poles for $F(A)$ where $A$ is the half-open interval $[-2,1[$ then

CONJECTURE

$$ F(-1) = q $$

Is this always true ?

What if there are 2 solutions $q_1,q_2$ ?